# How can I output sample rows from a .csv?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, csv-simple

I'm doing a lot of data merge printing and would like to be able to output, say, 10 samples from a large database. My goal would be to extract the 10 rows spread evenly from the supplied .csv (including the first and last row) and output this as a new .csv file.

Comment: share your sample input and expected output set

Comment: In a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) a row can span multiple lines because (quoted) cells can have newlines. `grep` is not going to deal with that correctly. If you are dealing with some restricted subset data without newlines, describe that exactly (and don't call it CSV)

Comment: You should not use "spread evenly" rows for a sample. That makes your sample vulnerable to repeated patterns (eg, you may pull the same time each day). Pre-generate 10 random numbers with the range [1, num_rows] and then select those records. Throw an error if any row numbers are the same, as then the population is too small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that your csv file has one line per row, meaning that there are no continued lines.  If the file is called `db.csv`, then you can get 10 lines, including the first and the last by using:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{next} FNR==1{n=NR-1} FNR>x || FNR==n{x+=n/9;print}' db.csv db.csv
```

#### How it works

Because the csv file is listed twice on the command line, `awk` will read through it twice.  The first is used to get the total number of lines.  The second time is used to print the 10 selected lines.

- `FNR==NR{next}`

  `NR` is the total number of records (lines) read so far.The file record number, `FNR`, is equal to the total number of records (lines) read so far from this file.  So, when `FNR==NR`, we are still reading the first file.  If so, we just jump to the `next` record.
- `FNR==1{n=NR-1}`

  If we reach this command, that means that we are on the first line of the second read through.  In that case, we know that the total number of records in the file is `NR-1`.  We save this number as `n`.
- `FNR>x || FNR==n{x+=n/9;print}`

  One the first line of the second read through, `FNR==1` and `x=0`.  Thus, `FNR>x` and we print that line.  We then increment `x` by `n/9` and print a line the next time that `FNR>x` and so on.

  The condition `FNR==n` assures that the last line in the file will be printed.

#### Example

Let us create a file with 101 lines:

```
$ seq 101 >db.csv
```

Now, we can use our `awk` command to print 10 lines from the file, including the first and last:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{next} FNR==1{n=NR-1} FNR>x || FNR==n{x+=n/9;print}' db.csv db.csv
1
12
23
34
45
57
68
79
90
101
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
SELECT your_column1, your_column2
FROM your_table_name
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/ouput.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

That works for linux
    on windows replace

```
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.csv'
```

with

```
INTO OUTFILE 'c:\output.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV files are not restricted and contain newlines, and commas within field values, you should use a real CSV parsing library e.g. the one available standard in python:

```
import csv

def select_evenly(file_name, nr):
    rows = []
    with open(file_name) as fp:
        for row in csv.reader(fp):
            rows.append(row)
    nr_rows = len(rows)
    step = (nr_rows - 2.0) / (nr - 1)
    yield rows[0]
    for x in range(1, nr-1):
        yield rows[int(x * step + 0.5)]
    yield rows[-1]

for line in select_evenly("test.csv", 10):
    print line
```